# IONIC2: Content Appearing Pushed To The Right

Tags: android, mobile, ionic2

I am having a problem on my Ionic2 application when deployed to an `android 4.2.2` device, all the content appears heavily padded to the right as shown in the image attachment.

[image]

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is that still happening if you run it on the browser but adding the platform in the url like this: `http://localhost:8100/?ionicPlatform=android`?

Comment: If l run it on the browser with the url you supplied it appears fine, but on the device its still not correct here is the code for my page. <ion-header>
    <ion-navbar calm>
        <ion-title>Phone Info</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content class="device">
    </ion-content>

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to connect your phone on your computer (USB)?
Enter chrome://inpect in your chrome navigator (computer), this is a good way to debug.

And if you try:

```
<ion-navbar calm>
    <ion-title>Title</ion-title>
</ion-navbar>
```

instead of:

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar calm>
        <ion-title>Title</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

what's the result?